# En Genexus X Evo 2, ¿cuando se exporta un objeto, se exporta su historia?

Tags: genexus

Cuando exportamos un objeto Genexus de una Kb a otra ¿es posible exportar su historia o siempre surge como un objeto nuevo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, la historia no se exporta cuando se hace un `Export` común.

Hay forma de exportar una versión histórica de un objeto, para eso primero tienes que marcar la versión que quieres exportar como "current" y exportar el objeto.

Podrías hacer esto con cada una de las versiones, y luego importarlas en orden. No creo que sea muy práctico... Habría que ver también cuál es el caso de uso, para qué necesitas la historia en la otra KB.